# How to add subview so that it overlaps another view?

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following subview

```
    webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 3, y: horizontalLine.frame.maxY + 8, width: self.view.frame.width-6, height: CGFloat(self.view.frame.height - 150)))
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(webView)
```

I want to add the following subview on top of it (not inside it).

```
 textSizeChangeView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: textBtn.frame.maxY, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 100))
    textSizeChangeView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.97, green: 0.98, blue: 0.98, alpha: 1.00)
    
    let mySlider = UISlider(frame:CGRect(x: 10, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width - 20, height: 30))
    self.textSizeChangeView.addSubview(mySlider)
    
    mySlider.center = self.textSizeChangeView.center
    
    mySlider.minimumValue = 1
    mySlider.maximumValue = 2
    mySlider.isContinuous = true
    mySlider.tintColor = UIColor(red: 0.33, green: 0.79, blue: 0.93, alpha: 1.00)
    textSizeChangeView.isHidden = true
    mySlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.sliderValueChanged(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)

    self.view.addSubview(self.textSizeChangeView)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're not supposed to set `center` like that, but why are you adding `mySlider` to `textSizeChangeView`?

Comment: i think you've done it. `webView` and `textSizeChangeView` have the same parent view, `webView` comes first, so it'll be drawn first, and `textSizeChangeView` will be drawn 2nd, "on top" of `webView` if they overlap

Answer (score 0):

The order of adding subviews matters.

If you want to make sure that `textSizeChangeView` will be on top of `webView` in case of overlapping then you need to make sure that `self.view.addSubview(webView)` is called before `self.view.addSubview(self.textSizeChangeView)`.